# Why return full html instead of data when passing angular variable to php?

Tags: php, angularjs

I tried to use $http to pass angular data to php, but by the code below, what returns as $message variable is the whole html code rather than desired data, please feel free to share your thought, thank you very much!

PHP Code

```
<?php
echo "
    <body>
        <section class=\"contact-form\">
                <table width=\"100%\">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan=\"2\">
                        <label for=\"message\">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"5\" id=\"message\" ng-model=\"message\"></textarea>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

                <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-block buttonSubmit\" >Send Email</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/contact.js\"></script>
    </body>";

    $from_angular = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input'));
    echo "<script>console.log('connect = ".$from_angular."');</script>";
    $message = $from_angular->message;
    echo "<script>console.log('message = ".$message."');</script>";
?>
```

Angular Code

```
var contact = angular.module('contact-form',[]);
contact.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.message = 'Today I would like to inform you that your work is pretty impressive. Hope we could get contact to each other and furtherly talk about a precious working position in my company. This position is related to Software Development, which is a perfect fit to your professional background.';

    $http({
        url: "./Contact.php",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: {
            message: $scope.message,
        }
    }).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    });
})
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP person ... but I would assume that you need to use a "POST", not a "GET". The "GET" gets data from the server (PHP). Use "POST" or "PUT" to pass data to the server.

Comment: @DeborahK, I tried before but still not work, thanks anyway.

Comment: you need to echo _one_ json-string, no html, no script tags, no js code. Just plain json.

Comment: Also, you're echoing `$from_angular`, which would be an object, if you did a POST instead. I also thing the data will be posted as proper form data, so you should use `$_POST['message']` to get the posted data, not `input://`.

Comment: What is the problem ? you PHP code is just weird, but you return what you `echo`. What is the bug here ?

Comment: @NanDeng, try using `POST` instead of `GET`. Also, in your JS code, you are sending the data as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`, but decoding it on the PHP side as `JSON`. Use `'application/json'` instead.

Comment: To extend what @NaijaProgrammer is saying, the default for `$http` is `'application/json'` so you can remove `headers`

Comment: It's easier to just have `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Then you don't need to fetch the input stream and decode the data. Just use the `$_POST`-super global to get the data in PHP (when you've changed the method to POST, that is)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sure but that also requires serializing the data differently if you want to use `$_POST[index]`. Default serialization with $http is JSON

Comment: @charlietfl - Doesn't angular do that for you if you set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson not by default, default is JSON serialization regardless of content type header. Using `file_get_contents('php://input')` is quite common to receive json

Comment: @charlietfl - Ah. I thought it was smart enough to do that for you. Even jQuery have done it for years :-p. You learn something new every day.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sure but defaults are different. If you want to send json with jQuery you have to stringify yourself also and set header yourself. Just opposite...not really different

Comment: @charlietfl - That's true, though.